# Changing column names in a migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class AddTimestampsToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :create_up, :datetime
    add_column :posts, :update_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

I need to correct `:create_up and :update_at` to `:created_at and :updated_at`

How can I achieve this?

THank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
def change
  rename_column :posts, :create_up, :created_at
  rename_column :posts, :update_at, :updated_at
end
```

The [ActiveRecord::Migration documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) lists the available transformations you can use.

Comment: `class AddTimestampsToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :posts, :created_at, :created_at, :datetime
    rename_column :posts, :updated_at, :updated_at, :datetime
  end
end`


IS this correct? Do I have to do rake db:migrate?

Comment: Add another migration, say "RenameTimestampsOnPosts" and add the change method above. Then run `rake db:migrate` and you should be good to go. :)

Comment: Can all of this be done from the CLI? E.g. `rails g migration RenameTimestampsOnPosts create_up:created_at, update_at:updated_at`?

Comment: I've only seen the command line parameters used to set up a `create_table` block. I'm not sure if it's possible to do what you suggest. Maybe that's a good candidate for a new question?